# About LR/SC in two soft threads on same hart

Tags: riscv

If I have two soft threads on the same hart, Thread #1 first execute an LR instruction, then #2 execute an LR instruction with the same address, and finally #1 SC to that address. Will this SC succeed? Which LR will be paired(#1 or #2) if successful?

[image: img]

The aq/rl bit is not set and all address of LR/SC are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two threads running on the same hart means that there has to be a context switch.

Reading [RISC-V Unprivileged ISA V20191213](https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/riscv-spec-20191213.pdf), I found this recommendation on page 50:

> A store-conditional instruction to a scratch word of memory should be used to forcibly invalidate any existing load reservation:
>
> - during a preemptive context switch, and
> - if necessary when changing virtual to physical address mappings,  such as when migrating pages that might contain an active reservation.

The commit message from [the commit that introduced this text](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/commit/73257004b84fafe8433ec3df1938345618c68fbb) elaborates:

> Commit 170f3c5 clarified that reservations can be cleared with an SC to
>   a dummy memory location. As discussed
>   <170f3c5#commitcomment-29386537>,
>   this patch makes it clear that the reservation "should" be cleared in
>   this way during a preemptive context switch.
>
> Anyone writing preemptive context switch code should be forcibly
>   clearing load reservations. Although other mechanisms might be used,
>   this is the standard way of doing it (hence "should" rather than
>   "must").

The Linux kernel does this in [entry.S](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a99efa00891b66405ebd25e49868efc701fe1546/arch/riscv/kernel/entry.S#L101):

```
/*
 * The current load reservation is effectively part of the processor's
 * state, in the sense that load reservations cannot be shared between
 * different hart contexts.  We can't actually save and restore a load
 * reservation, so instead here we clear any existing reservation --
 * it's always legal for implementations to clear load reservations at
 * any point (as long as the forward progress guarantee is kept, but
 * we'll ignore that here).
 *
 * Dangling load reservations can be the result of taking a trap in the
 * middle of an LR/SC sequence, but can also be the result of a taken
 * forward branch around an SC -- which is how we implement CAS.  As a
 * result we need to clear reservations between the last CAS and the
 * jump back to the new context.  While it is unlikely the store
 * completes, implementations are allowed to expand reservations to be
 * arbitrarily large.
 */
REG_L  a2, PT_EPC(sp)
REG_SC x0, a2, PT_EPC(sp)
```

This code does a regular load of some memory, then uses an `SC` to write the same value back to the same location. The `SC` clears any reservations, and it doesn't matter if it succeeds or not.

Anyway, in preemptive multitasking systems, a program can expect the operating system kernel to invalidate any reservations during context switches. In such a system, if you're switched out in the middle of your `LR/SC` sequence, your `SC` instruction will always fail.

In cooperative multitasking systems (where your program is only switched out when it chooses to yield), your `SC` instruction could succeed -- but only if you yield in the middle of your `LR/SC` sequence. *And* the other thread does the same.

We would have a code sequence like this:

```
Thread A    Thread B
----------------------
LR
yield
            LR
            yield
SC
yield
            SC
```

As I understand the spec, A's `SC` will succeed, while B's `SC` will fail. The `SC` instruction will always pair with the most recent `LR` instruction, so the successful `SC` from thread A will pair with the `LR` from thread B.

But this code is nonsense. The spec even [used to contain recommendations against it](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/commit/170f3c52bd134ac90c3467f77925fdaa68e9b8f6):

> Cooperative user-level context switches might not cause a load reservation
>   to be yielded, so user-level threads should generally avoid voluntary
>   context switches in the middle of an LR/SC sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have another question about how does the kernel invalidate any reservations during the preemptive context switch? Because I don't seem to find any instructions to invalidate reservation?

Comment: "A store-conditional instruction to a scratch word of memory should be used to forcibly invalidate any existing load reservation" -- I'll add some details to the answer.